# Two-way Hybrid Connections

Tags: azure, azure-appservice, azure-hybrid-connections

I established a Hybrid Connection from App Service to on-premises by using Hybrid Connection Manager (HCM).
Is it possible to connect the other way from on-premises to the App Service?
This would be needed to have a two-way communication channel.

To be clear: I don't need any help regarding the setup of the Hybrid Conenction Manager. Everything is working fine. I also can reach the on-prem resource from App Service by using `curl`. So is there a way to `curl` the App Service from on-premises server where HCM is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HCM is one way - it's only for outbound calls from App Service to the machine where the HCM is installed. To connect the other way, you need to ensure your access restrictions on the App Service allow inbound connectivity from on-prem. If that is allowed, you should be able to reach your App Service over the public internet, ExpressRoute, vpn gateway, or whichever connection you've configured. Since you're using HCM, I'd assume that would mean public internet.

Comment: Yes, you're right. We already figured this out. We're now going to use VPN gateway.